# Memory diagram of dynamic allocation of Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: c++, dynamic, multidimensional-array

Here are two ways to dynamically allocate a multidimensional array that I know:

```
int (*numbers)[4] = new int[3][4]
```

and

```
int **numbers = new int*[3];
```

Do these two represent the same thing in memory?. What and how do they represent, actually? 
(a memory diagram would really help!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the first will create 12 ints (3*4), in memory they will be sequentially laid out. The second creates 3 pointers to integers

Ie the first will be laid out like

```
[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8][9,10,11,12]
```

so you have 3 4 element arrays of integers, wheras the second example is going to look more like

```
[0x12345678,0x12345678,0x12345678]
```

ie, 3 uninitialized pointers to integers

Comment: can you explain more what "numbers" represent?

Comment: The first `numbers` is a pointer to an array of 4 integers. The second `numbers` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer.

Comment: How can a pointer to an array of 4 integers hold address of 12 ints?
How can a pointer to a pointer to an integer hold address of 3 pointers to integer?
Sorry I'm a bit confused

Comment: A pointer doesn't "hold" anything, the value of a pointer is the memory address where something is. So in the first case, the value of `numbers` is the memory address of the first element of the first array of 4 integers. For the second `numbers`, the value of `numbers` is the memory address of the first pointer in your 3 pointer array.